# How to run a bash command via docker exec using Docker.Dotnet

Tags: docker, docker.dotnet

I am trying to check if a file exists on a docker container. I am doing this using a docker exec. I can run the command:

```
docker exec [ContainerName] /bin/bash -c "sudo test -f "/repositories/gubbins/file.txt" && echo "true""
```

In a bash shell and it will do as I desire.

However when I try to execute this using Docker.DotNet as below then it fails:

```
using (var tty = await _dockerClient.Exec.StartAndAttachContainerExecAsync(
    (await _dockerClient.Exec.ExecCreateContainerAsync(
        containerName,
        new ContainerExecCreateParameters
        {
            AttachStdin = true,
            AttachStderr = true,
            AttachStdout = true,
            Tty = true,
            Detach = false,
            Privileged = true,
            Cmd = new List<string>
            {
                "/bin/bash",
                "-c",
                "\"sudo test -f \"/repositories/gubbins/file.txt\" && echo \"true\"\"",
            }
        })).ID,
    true))
{
    var (stdOut, stdError) = await tty.ReadOutputToEndAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Standard Out is: /bin/bash: sudo test -f /repositories/gubbins/file.txt && echo true: No such file or directory

I have tried many permutations of quotes, double quotes, splitting command up etc but cannot get it to work. The issue appears to be that I am using '&&'. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I can't test this out, but it looks to me like you are over-quoting the command. E.g., you've got `"\"sudo ...`, but you don't need those inside quotes: `"sudo test -f \"...\""`.

Comment: You probably don't need `sudo` (if it works at all), or the `bash -c` wrapper; it's probably enough to dixectly run `{"test", "-f", "file.txt"}` and check the container's exit code.  I'd even think hard about whether you need this call at all – can you do the non-Docker equivalent and "go inside" your process to see if the variable `stdOut` exists?

Comment: @larsks no that's not it I'm afraid. That was one of the many permutations I tried already.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not sure what you mean by "the non-Docker equivalent and "go inside" your process to see if the variable stdOut exists"? Could you clarify please? The stdOut variable is just a string containing whatever the shell printed to standard out. Also I'm afraid I don't understand your other suggestion either, are you able to clarify that for me please?

Comment: The container is an isolated environment with its own isolated filesystem.  It can be useful to think about the container as just a wrapper around the process.  Why do you need to look inside the isolation layer?

Comment: I am using Selenium docker containers to run some automated tests of a web application. The .NET code executing these tests is running on the local machine. In some cases (where the tests download a file from the app) I need to retrieve a file from the container to read it/verify it in the .NET code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve what I want by using the `IExecOperations.InspectContainerExecAsync` method:

```
var execInstanceId = (await _dockerClient.Exec.ExecCreateContainerAsync(
        containerName,
        new ContainerExecCreateParameters
        {
            AttachStdin = true,
            AttachStderr = true,
            AttachStdout = true,
            Tty = true,
            Detach = false,
            Privileged = true,
            Cmd = new List<string>
            {
                "sudo",
                "test",
                "-f",
                $"{containerFilePath}"
            }
        })).ID;

using (var tty = await _dockerClient.Exec.StartAndAttachContainerExecAsync(execInstanceId, true))
{
    var (stdOut, stdError) = await tty.ReadOutputToEndAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdError))
    {
        throw new TestExecutionMachineException(
            $"Something went wrong while checking if file '{containerFilePath}' exists", stdOut, stdError);
    }

    var execInspectResponse = await _dockerClient.Exec.InspectContainerExecAsync(execInstanceId);

    if (execInspectResponse.ExitCode == 0)
        return true;

    if (execInspectResponse.ExitCode == 1)
        return false;

    throw new TestExecutionMachineException($"Something went wrong while checking if file '{containerFilePath}' exists", stdOut);
}
```

So we inspect the exec instance and check the exit code. If 0 then the file exists, if 1 it does not, and anything else would be some kind of error.